# Storing currency exchange data for android app

Tags: java, android

I'm hoping this will be a fairly basic question. I've been playing around with android development in the last couple days and I'm still missing some of the simple things.

I'm working on an app which needs to convert between currencies. I know that I can get recent data with queries like [this](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22USDEUR%22,%20%22USDGBP%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys).

I want to be able to save this information and allow it to be updated on request. I feel like the natural way to do this would be using an android resource file. It would be ideal if someone could (as explicitly as possible) explain how I could make the query, save it to a resource file, and then read the conversion rates from the resource file in the future.

I understand I could just make the request live each time the data is needed but I'd prefer to have something saved (so the rates can be used offline).

Thanks in advance all.

**UPDATE:**

Though Vulovic's answer is correct, and I intend to use this approach in the future. For now I have found it is simple to implement the SharedPreference class to store Currency:Rate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you need to create SQLite database. Here is a good tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will be exactly what I need. I'll take some time to read through it now and if all's good I'll choose this answer :).

Comment: Its working for me, so I dont think you will have a problem with it :)

Comment: I haven't implemented yet of course, but I am certain this is what I was looking for. Thanks Vulovic!